# Heatmap with Gnuplot on a non-uniform grid

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

I would like to create a heatmap with gnuplot based on a non-uniform grid, meaning that my x axis bins do not have all the same width, and I can't figure out how to do that because when I plot my data with for example "with image" I get uniformly sized boxes which do no correspond to my coordinates at all (because "image" treats the data just as matrix I guess). So I would like to find a method to get non-uniform boxes which are also positioned in the right place on the Cartesian plane.

My data look something like this:

```
1 1 0.2
1 2 0.8
1 3 0.1
1 4 0.2

2 1 0.7
2 2 0.2
2 3 0.3
2 4 0.1

5 1 0.2
5 2 0.4
5 3 0.1
5 4 0.9

7 1 0.3
7 2 0.2
7 3 0.9
7 4 0.6
```

If I run this command on Gnuplot

```
set xrange [1:10]
p 'mydata.dat' with image
```

I get an image with 16 boxes that have the same width and height (apparently I don't have enough "reputation" on Stackoverflow to post an image, otherwise I would), but ideally I would like the boxes to have different widths and be in the right place on the plane. For example the first box should range from 1 to 2, the second one from 2 to 5, the third one from 5 to 7, and the last one from 7 to 10 (which is why I wrote `set xrange [1:10]`).

Could anyone help me please? Thank you very much!

Comment: You should post your code otherwise it will be closed as off-topic. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest (maybe only viable) way is to add some dummy data points and use `splot ... with pm3d`. This plotting style handles heatmaps with general quadrangles.

The `image` plotting style plots one box (one big pixel) for each data point, while `pm3d` takes each data point as corner of one or more quadrangles. The color of each quadrangles is determined by the values of the corners and is adjustable with `set pm3d corners2color`.

So, in your case you need to expand the `4x4` matrix to a `5x5` matrix (expand to right and top), but select the lower left corner to determine the color `set pm3d corners2color c1`.

The changed data file is then:

```
1 1 0.2
1 2 0.8
1 3 0.1
1 4 0.2
1 5 0.5

2 1 0.7
2 2 0.2
2 3 0.3
2 4 0.1
2 5 0.5

5 1 0.2
5 2 0.4
5 3 0.1
5 4 0.9
5 5 0.5

7 1 0.3
7 2 0.2
7 3 0.9
7 4 0.6
7 5 0.5

10 1 0.5
10 2 0.5
10 3 0.5
10 4 0.5
10 5 0.5
```

To plot it use

```
set pm3d map corners2color c1
set autoscale fix
set ytics 1
splot 'mydata.dat' using 1:($2-0.5):3 notitle
```

The result with 4.6.3 is:

[image]

In general, the `z`-value of the dummy data points doesn't matter, but in the above script it should lay somewhere between minimum and maximum values to allow `set autoscale fix` to work properly on the color scale.

If you don't want to change the data file manually, you could do it with some script, but that's a different question.

Comment: Thank you very much Christoph, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution without `splot ... pm3d`, but with `boxxyerror`.
If you plot data it should go as automatic as possible and there should be no need to "invent" and manually add data.

The following solution (a little bit more complex) takes care about the widths (+/-dx) and heights (+/-dy) of the boxes according to the following principle:

- if it is an "inner" box, take half the distance to the adjacent datapoint on that side
- if it is an "outer" box, take half the distance to the adjacent "inner" datapoint

Here, x-distances are irregular and y-distances are regular, but y-distances could also be irregular.

**Data:** `SO19294342.dat`

```
1 1 0.2
1 2 0.8
1 3 0.1
1 4 0.2

2 1 0.7
2 2 0.2
2 3 0.3
2 4 0.1

5 1 0.2
5 2 0.4
5 3 0.1
5 4 0.9

7 1 0.3
7 2 0.2
7 3 0.9
7 4 0.6
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### heatmap with boxxyerror and variable box-sizes
reset

FILE = "SO/SO19294342.dat"

set style fill solid 1.0
set tics out
set size ratio -1

# extract x-positions
Xs = Ys = ''
Nx = Ny = 0
b = -1
stats FILE u (column(-1)!=b ? (Nx=Nx+1, Xs=Xs.sprintf(" %g",$1), b=column(-1)) : 0, \
              column(-1)==0 ? (Ny=Ny+1, Ys=Ys.sprintf(" %g",$2)) : 0) nooutput

d(vs,n0,n1) = abs(real(word(vs,n0))-real(word(vs,n1)))/2
dn(vs,n)    = (n==1 ? (n0=1,n1=2) : (n0=n,n1=n-1), -d(vs,n0,n1))
dp(vs,n)    = (Ns=words(vs), n==Ns ? (n0=Ns-1,n1=Ns) : (n0=n,n1=n+1), d(vs,n0,n1))

plot FILE u 1:2:($1+dn(Xs,column(-1)+1)):($1+dp(Xs,column(-1)+1)):\
                 ($2+dn(Ys,int(column(0))%Ny+1)):($2+dp(Ys,int(column(0))%Ny+1)):3 w boxxy palette notitle
### end of script
```

For gnuplot>=4.6.5 you could add `:xtic(1):xtic(2)` to the plot command to only show your x- and y-coordinates as x,y-ticlabels.

```
plot FILE u 1:2:($1+dn(Xs,column(-1)+1)):($1+dp(Xs,column(-1)+1)):\
                 ($2+dn(Ys,int(column(0))%Ny+1)):($2+dp(Ys,int(column(0))%Ny+1)):3:\
                 xtic(1):ytic(2) w boxxy palette notitle
```

And for gnuplot>=5.0.0 you could add `noextend` to the ranges to avoid white  areas on the sides:

```
set xrange[:] noextend
set yrange[:] noextend
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0)

[image]