# automate gnu-plot heatmap on non-uniform grid with bash

Tags: bash, shell, gnuplot, heatmap

I found this very helpful post here on plotting a heat-map on a non-uniform grid: [Heatmap with Gnuplot on a non-uniform grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294342/heatmap-with-gnuplot-on-a-non-uniform-grid)

Now everything works great if I put the suggested commands manually in gnuplot. However, I want to automate the graph by writing a shell-script that I can call directly in my fortran code.

This is the script (Map_Ent.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot <<- EOF

set pm3d map corners2color c1
set autoscale fix
set ytics 1
splot 'Career_Choice.txt' using 1:($2-0.5):3  

EOF

eog Ent_map.png &
```

And this is how I call it in Fortran:

```
call SYSTEM('bash ./Map_Ent.sh')
```

However my graph is completely white when I do it this way. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I would be very thankful for any suggestions!

Comment: `gnuplot <<- EOF`  how about removing `-` just after `<<`

Comment: Yes I actually started without the - and it did not work either.

Comment: I tried the persist as well. But still the graph is completely empty. The weird thing is that it works perfectly when I type it manually in gnuplot.

Comment: What happens when you call the script on command prompt i.e. not from your fortran progam. call it like `bash scriptname` without `./`

Comment: the same. It shows the graph outlines etc. but the "filling" is white.

Comment: the one error message I get in all the cases is the following: empty y range [-0.5:-0.5], adjusting to [-0.505:-0.495]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$2` is interpreted by bash and evaluates to nothing. Therefore, gnuplot plots only `-0.5`. `$2` is a shortcut for `column(2)`. Just use the latter and it should work fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnuplot <<- EOF

set pm3d map corners2color c1
set autoscale fix
set ytics 1
splot 'Career_Choice.txt' using 1:(column(2)-0.5):3  

EOF
```

There is no need to use bash as intermediate step, just use a gnuplot script:

`file.gp`:

```
set pm3d map corners2color c1
set autoscale fix
set ytics 1
splot 'Career_Choice.txt' using 1:(column(2)-0.5):3
```

And then

```
call SYSTEM('gnuplot -persist file.gp')
```

(I'm not sure about the fortran call, just copied from the question).

Comment: Thank you so much! The gnuplot script version works perfectly and does everything I want!