# GNUPLOT: plot nonuniform matrix issue

Tags: matrix, plot, gnuplot

i am trying to plot a matrix from an ascii file shaped as:

```
<N+1>  <y0>   <y1>   <y2>  ...  <yN>
<x0> <z0,0> <z0,1> <z0,2> ... <z0,N>
<x1> <z1,0> <z1,1> <z1,2> ... <z1,N>
```

as from gnuplot manual. the x's and the y's are not uniformly distributed, so that the grid over which i want to plot the matrix is rectangular but not equispaced. If i plot it as

```
p 'datafile.dat' nonuniform matrix with image
```

i have a nice coloured picture, with axes reporting the grid points interval, but the matrix is still represented as if the grid is equispaced.

How can i get rid of it? Thak you

```
G N U P L O T
      Version 5.0 patchlevel rc2    last modified 2014-08-28
```

Comment: The `image` plotting style works only with equidistant grids

Comment: I see, thank you Christoph. Finally i discovered the pm3d style, that did it.

Comment: Depending on your data amount you must have in mind, that pm3d plots rectangles between four adjacent data point and interpolates the color value. I was looking for another question with a similar task were it was important to exactly reproduce the underlying nonuniform grid. Maybe I'll find it.

Comment: It would be great if you can find it, otherwise thank you for your help.

Comment: See [Heatmap with Gnuplot on a non-uniform grid](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19294342/2604213)